# Cover page for PDF in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, tex

I want to make a cover page for my thesis. Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86Cke.png) would be great. It's there a way to do it in R Markdown? Or maybe in a .tex file and then add it to the .rmd? I'm knitting into a pdf.

Comment: Have you had a look how folks do it in the thesisdown templates (https://github.com/ismayc/thesisdown)?

Comment: I looked but they dont do fancy cover pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to put a LaTeX Preamble into the .Rmd document. Change `test.tex` to the file path of your preamble. The preamble should only contain LaTeX code that comes after your `\documentclass{article}` declaration and before your `\begin{document}` declaration.

```yaml
Output:
    pdf_document:
        includes:
            in_header: “test.tex”
```

in that preamble you can try this for a custom title page:

```latex
\usepackage{titling}
    \title{\huge{<++>}}
    \author{\href{mailto:your@email.com}{Author Name}}
    \date{\today}
```

and to render the title page put this in the .Rmd towards the top of the document:

```latex
   \begin{titlepage}
           \maketitle
           \thispagestyle{empty}
           \clearpage
   \end{titlepage}
```

You could also try [TeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) for lots of LaTeX questions.